# Switch WiFi mode from AP to STA

Tags: c++, c, wifi, esp32, esp-idf

I'm working on project with **ESP32-S2-Saola-1M** board in C/C++ via **ESP-IDF** framework. At the beginning I initialize a Wi-Fi in an AP mode and starts the HTTP WebServer to get WiFi data from user through browser. After the user saves his Wi-Fi data (SSID and Passwd) throught page, the
HTTP server should shut down and Wi-Fi switch from AP mode to STA mode - connect to user's Wi-Fi. I have problem with this part. I don't know how to solve this elegantly and in principle correctly. So can someone describe me any solutions or better ideas please?

I thought of using method with *while* cycle and POST handler. After the data comes from page via POST request, handler saves them and set some bool property (e.g. *hasData* in code below) to true and *while* cycle in method breaks/stops and other code in application can continue. Something like semaphore. Simply:

1. start Wi-Fi (AP mode)
2. start webserver
3. wait until user sends his Wi-Fi data
4. stop webserver
5. stop Wi-Fi AP mode -> switch to STA mode
6. next actions... (measure, send data out, deep sleep etc.)

Pseudo code:

```c
bool hasData = false;

static esp_err_t postHandler(httpd_req_t *request)
{
    .
    . //saves data from POST request
    . 

    hasData = true;

    return ESP_OK;
}


void waitForUser(void)
{
    while(hasData != true) {
        //just wait
    }
}


static const httpd_uri_t postData = {
    .uri = "/connection",
    .method = HTTP_POST,
    .handler = postHandler,
    .user_ctx = NULL
    };


static httpd_handle_t start_webserver(void)
{
    httpd_handle_t server = NULL;
    httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();

    if (httpd_start(&server, &config) == ESP_OK) {

        httpd_register_uri_handler(server, &postData);

        return server;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void stop_webserver(httpd_handle_t server)
{
    if (server) {
        httpd_stop(server);
    }
}


void wifiAPInit(void)
{
    .
    . //Initialize wifi config for AP mode and start wifi
    .
}


void app_main(void)
{
    .
    . //Initialize NVS and others...
    .

    httpd_handle_t server = NULL;
    wifiAPinit();
    server = start_webserver();
    waitForUser();
    stop_webserver(server);
    .
    . // start Wifi in STA mode and continue...
    .
}
```

Is this principle correct?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: I don't understand "switch to STA mode and connect to wifi" What wifi does it connect to?

Comment: I mean ESP connect to user's Wi-Fi as station

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the easiest approach is to just reboot (`esp_restart()`) after saving new configuration.

Then select the right mode after reading the configuration on boot.

```
void app_main()
{
    // init NVS
    // load configuration from NVS
    if (config.wifiSSID.empty()) {
        startAPmode();
    } else {
        startSTAmode(config.wifiSSID, config.wifiPassword);
    }
    start_webserver();
    // etc ...
}
```

Comment: this could be, but webserver should stop when ESP is in STA mode. And next question, what if user wanted to reconfigure SSID and Password?

Comment: Then move `start_webserver();` to inside `if (AP mode) { ... }`. But then how will you reconfigure SSID? You can add a "hard reset" button to delete configuration, or add a command-line interface for UART console. You can look around in [this project](https://github.com/rustyx/itho-esp/tree/main/main) for a command-line interface, although the project might be a bit large to browse.

Comment: Ok. Use NVS for store SSID and Passwd and reboot is good. I have another next problem. I'll keep WebServer set ON for reconfiguration. But after start_webserver() I need to create xTask for measuring, send measured data and set ESP into Deep Sleep. The entire device will be powered by the battery. So if I create right after task and subsequent introduction into Deep Sleep, it will not be possible to change the configuration. Because I think, that webserver doesn't work in Deep Sleep mode, right? So do you have any idea how to wait for possible reconfiguration and start measurement after that?

Comment: If this question is answered, it's better to accept it and ask a new one. I must admit I don't know how to handle deep sleep mode. I think in deep sleep also wi-fi is off. Perhaps you can use MQTT or smth like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Both Sta and Ap at the same time

```
void connectSTA(char *ssid, char *pass)
{
    wifi_config_t wifi_config;
    memset(&wifi_config, 0, sizeof(wifi_config));
    strcpy((char *)wifi_config.sta.ssid, said);
    strcpy((char *)wifi_config.sta.password, pass);
    esp_wifi_set_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &wifi_config);
}

void connectAP()
{
    wifi_config_t wifi_config =
        {
            .ap = {
                .ssid = "my esp32",
                .password = "P@ssword",
                .max_connection = 4,
                .authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK}};
    esp_wifi_set_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_AP, &wifi_config);
}

void wifiInit(void *params)
{

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());

    tcpip_adapter_init();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_init(event_handler, NULL));

    nvs_handle_t nvs;
    nvs_open("wifiCreds", NVS_READWRITE, &nvs);

    size_t ssidLen, passLen;
    char *ssid = NULL, *pass = NULL;

    if (nvs_get_str(nvs, "ssid", NULL, &ssidLen) == ESP_OK)
    {
        if (ssidLen > 0)
        {
            ssid = malloc(ssidLen);
            nvs_get_str(nvs, "ssid", ssid, &ssidLen);
        }
    }

    if (nvs_get_str(nvs, "pass", NULL, &passLen) == ESP_OK)
    {
        if (passLen > 0)
        {
            pass = malloc(passLen);
            nvs_get_str(nvs, "pass", pass, &passLen);
        }
    }

    wifi_init_config_t wifi_init_config = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&wifi_init_config));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_APSTA));
    connectAP();
    if (ssid != NULL && pass != NULL)
    {
        connectSTA(ssid, pass);
    }

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());
}
```